# MBProgressHUD UIViewController animation inconsistent

Tags: ios, mbprogresshud

In this project, I am using a MBProgressHUD when I get JSON content from a server.
The first time I start my app, the animation from my MenuViewController to my Page works fine. But when I go back to my Menu and to the Page again, no viewcontroller switch animation is shown.
It only happens when I add the MBProgressHUD functionality..

My Page ViewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadPage) withObject:nil];
}
```

The loadPage method, simplified:

```
-(void) loadPage {
    //loading functionality, deleted for now.


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

         [_lblTitle setText: [postsArray[0] objectForKey:@"title"]];
         [_webview loadHTMLString:[postsArray[0] objectForKey:@"content"] baseURL:nil];
         [HUD hide:YES];
    });

}
```

So when I delete the 2nd and 3rth line in viewDidLoad and the HUD hide, the animation works fine every time.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadPage) withObject:nil];
```

with

```
MBProgressHUD *searchHUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
        searchHUD.dimBackground=YES;
        searchHUD.animationType = MBProgressHUDAnimationZoom;
        [self.view addSubview:searchHUD];
        [searchHUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadPage) onTarget:self withObject:Nil animated:YES];
```

Reason: MBProgressHud provides this functionality to run any method in background thread..

Comment: This seems to work! I tried this before, but my title label wasn't filled for some reason and the back button (not shown in my example code) wasn't shown either.. But it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this
in your `-(void)viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];
    HUD.delegate = self;

    [HUD show:YES];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadPage) withObject:nil];
}
```

Comment: I tried this (and added the MBProgressHUDDelegate to my .h file), but still no animation..

Answer (score 0):

```
//MBProgressHUD provides an easy way to execute code in background you don't need to create separate method for each task you wish to execute with HUD

MBProgressHUD *hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
[self.view addSubview:hud];

[hud showAnimated:YES whileExecutingBlock:^{
    //Write the code you wish to execute with an indicator
    // e.g. write the code to call web-service

// Last but not the least if you are doing any UI related task then use

    // Write UI related code to be executed on main queue
//e.g. if you are using UITableView to show retrieved data from server
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
[self.tableView reloadData];

});


} completionBlock:^{
    [hud removeFromSuperview];
}];
```